# Presenting images dynamically multirow multicolumn

Tags: css, multiple-columns, viewport, image-scaling, landscape-portrait

I want to represent around 20 images on a webpage. The images can have a portrait or landscape orientation. I'd like to structure them in a 3 per row fashion on bigger screens, decreasing to a 1 per row on mobile phones, maybe 2 per row for tablet-like devices. But layout could also depend on the orientation of the viewport. I have these requirements:

- The row-height should be the maximum height of any photo in the row. For example: with two portrait photos and one landscape in a row, the row height becomes the height of the portrait photos.
- The landscape photo should be placed in the center of its cell and leave empty space on top/bottom.
- The portrait photos should fully occupy their cells.
- Columns should be equally divided over the available width (33.33%, 50% or 100% screenwidth).
- I also would like the page to be responsive, i.e. the images have to shrink/enlarge depending on the browser screen width/height.
- A caption per photo to be located in the center of the picture just under the top of the image, to display a counter or small descriptive text.

I've read many articles not to go with the table-solution, but rather with a div-solution. Any help would be appreciated highly.

Comment: I would suggest Grid, Flexbox or Masonry for this particular project.

Comment: Hi Jake, thanks for your response. 
That would indeed be a solution, if displaying the pictures was the only object.
However, I need the pictures to be responsive, i.e. when doubleclicked I need some follow up for my site.
Although I'm able to do some javascripting, I'm not the kind of expert that can adapt the underlying javascript of the packages you mention to hook into the code already present on my site. So I'm trying to get the correct css-rules to tackle the representation of the images. From there I think I would be able to handle the remaining scripting to accomplish my project.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is off-topic for SO. More so, you're not showing us a clear image or code example of what you want to achieve which makes helping you not really easy I'm afraid..

Comment: @Jake1964 You are asking questions about the fundamental rules of CSS and responsive development, which is a topic far too broad for stackoverflow. You could potentially narrow the scope of your question by posting the markup you'd like to make work in this fashion or you may want to review some introductory guides to modern CSS and responsive development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gallery {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}
.gallery > li {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: stretch;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .gallery > li {
    flex-basis: calc(100% / 2);
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .gallery > li {
    flex-basis: calc(100% / 1);
  }
}
.gallery > li > figure {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
.gallery > li > figure img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  order: 1;
}
.gallery > li > figure figcaption {
  order: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ul class="gallery"> 
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/g/200/300?image=0" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=10" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=20" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=30" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/g/300/300?image=40" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=50" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=60" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/g/200/300?image=70" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=80" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=90" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=100" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=110" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/g/200/300?image=120" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=130" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=140" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=151" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=160" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=170" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=180" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
  <li><figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=190" alt=""><figcaption>This is a caption</figcaption></figure></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Jake1964 If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as the accepted answer (click the checkmark by the answer's voting buttons) to indicate to future viewers that the answer solved your problem. Likewise, if the answer is helpful in general, upvoting the answer is encouraged.